# Accessing Data members of callee class from Aspect functions

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a `DoStuff` class which has instances of `ServiceSAO` and `ServiceInput` as its data members. Whenever I invoke a function lets say `setDetail(String)`, I have set up an advice to call `publishEvent()`. To call `publishEvent()`, I require the `ServiceSAO` and `ServiceInput` instances of the DoStuff class. 
The question is how do I access data members(`ServiceSAO` and `ServiceInput`) of a callee class(`DoStuff`) from the aspect function(`publishEvent`)?

**DoStuff.java**

```
public class DoStuff{
     @Autowired
     private ServiceSAO serviceSAO;
     private ServiceInput serviceInput;
     void init(){
          serviceSAO = new serviceSAO();
          serviceInput = ServiceUtil.getServiceInput(hostname,"test",....);
      }



  @PublishEventToService
     public void hello(){
          serviceInput.setDetail("batman");
      }

}
```

**PublishEventToServiceAspect.java**

```
@Aspect
public class PublishEventToServiceAspect{
       @After("execution(* com.xyz.ServiceInput.setDetails(..)) && @annotation(PublishEventToService)")
       public void publishEvent()
{
    String detail = serviceInput.getDetails();   //how can I get serviceInput here??
    someFuntion(serviceSAO, serviceInput);            //even tougher would be to get the serviceSAO instance??
}
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Note that I can have various DoStuff classes. All of them might want to call publishEvent() and therefore I need a generic method to extract the instances.

**EDIT 2**
I am able to get the ServiceInput instance now using (ServiceInput)joinPoint.getTarget()
Any way to access ServiceSAO?

Comment: `serviceInput` it's an instance created and managed by Spring? Please, post more source code.

Comment: Original source code is pretty large. Please look at the update. @AndreiStefan

Comment: Add as parameters of your `publishEvent` method: `JoinPoint joinPoint, PublichEventToService annotation`, the `JoinPoint` have the method `getTarget`, witch return the `DoStuff` bean, like this https://github.com/fpuna-cia/karaku/blob/master/src/main/java/py/una/pol/karaku/audit/Auditor.java

Comment: @AVolpe All right. But it is still not clear how the fields of Object target are accessed.

Comment: I need the instances of SAO and Input so that I can pass it to another function.

Comment: You can try `((DoStuff) joinPoint.getTarget()).getServiceSAO();`. I recommend to create a interface with the desired public methods, and cast the `joinPoint.getTarget()` to the interface and call the methods. See the method `doIt` here https://github.com/fpuna-cia/karaku/blob/master/src/main/java/py/una/pol/karaku/security/KarakuSecurity.java. It cast to a interfaces and call the desired methods.

Comment: is there any way I can get the ServiceInput instance of DoStuff? Note that I can have various DoStuff classes i.e. DoStuff1, DoStuff2 etc. and all of them will be using this aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a disclaimer: I know a lot about AspectJ, but very little about Spring. So I am going to give a pure AspectJ example here.

Next, a correction: You claim you want to access ***callee*** members and Serge Ballesta's answer is also about the callee (`target()` binding). But this contradicts what you describe in your code snippet, because there you do not want to access anything related to the callee (`ServiceInput` object), but members of the ***caller*** (`DoStuff` object). For the caller you need `this()` binding, not `target()`.

Then another, subtle problem: The members you are trying to accesss are actually private, i.e. in order to access them you either need to have public getters for them or use a **privileged aspect**. I am assuming there are no getters because your code snippet does not show any. Now there is a limitation in AspectJ: Privileged aspects are only available in native AspectJ syntax, [not in annotation-style @AspectJ syntax](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspects.html). Thus, I am going to use native syntax in my solution. If you do have public getters or can easily add them to your classes, you can convert the aspect to @AspectJ syntax without the need for privileged access.

I am further assuming that you are not limited to "AOP lite", i.e. Spring AOP, but willing to use full-blown AspectJ (which is fully compatible with Spring, too).

**Dummy helper classes:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ServiceSAO {
    private String id;
    public ServiceSAO(String id) { this.id = id; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "ServiceSAO [id=" + id + "]"; }
}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ServiceInput {
    private String id;
    private String detail;

    public ServiceInput(String id) { this.id = id; }
    public void setDetail(String detail) { this.detail = detail; }
    @Override public String toString() { return "ServiceInput [id=" + id + ", detail=" + detail + "]"; }
}
```

--

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PublishEventToService {}
```

**Application class with private members and sample main method:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class DoStuff {
    private ServiceSAO serviceSAO;
    private ServiceInput serviceInput;

    void init() {
        serviceSAO = new ServiceSAO("SAO");
        serviceInput = new ServiceInput("Input");
    }

    @PublishEventToService
    public void hello() {
        serviceInput.setDetail("batman");
    }

//  @PublishEventToService
    public void otherMethod() {
        serviceInput.setDetail("foobar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoStuff doStuff = new DoStuff();
        doStuff.init();
        doStuff.hello();
        doStuff.otherMethod();
    }
}
```

Please note that `hello()` is annotated, but `otherMethod()` is not (the annotation is commented out). I.e. we expect the advice to be triggered for the former, but not the latter.

**Privileged aspect accessing private members:**

```
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.ServiceInput;
import de.scrum_master.app.PublishEventToService;
import de.scrum_master.app.DoStuff;

public privileged aspect PublishEventToServiceAspect {
    pointcut setDetail(DoStuff caller) :
        call(* ServiceInput.setDetail(..)) &&
        cflow(execution(@PublishEventToService * DoStuff+.*(..))) &&
        this(caller);

    after(DoStuff caller) : setDetail(caller) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);        
        System.out.println("  " + caller.serviceSAO);       
        System.out.println("  " + caller.serviceInput);     
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are intercepting the method `call()` for `ServiceInput.setDetail(..)` here rather than the `execution()` because we want to access something in the caller's context, not the callee's. Please also note that `call()` is only available in AspectJ, not in Spring AOP where you are limited to `execution()` pointcuts.

We also want to make sure that only calls are intercepted which are in the control flow (`cflow()`) of any currently executed methods of class `DoStuff` or its subclasses (thus the "+" in `DoStuff+`) annotated by `@PublishEventToService`.

Last but not least we want to make sure that the caller (`this()`) is assigned to a `DoStuff` binding named `doStuff` which we can use in our advice.

If all these conditions are true, let us print the joinpoint and the caller's private members in order to prove that it actually works.

**Sample output:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.DoStuff.hello())
  ServiceSAO [id=SAO]
  ServiceInput [id=Input, detail=batman]
```

This is exactly what we expect and what you asked for. Now if we remove the comment from the annotation of `otherMethod()`, we have two annotated methods and the aspect prints:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.DoStuff.hello())
  ServiceSAO [id=SAO]
  ServiceInput [id=Input, detail=batman]
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.DoStuff.otherMethod())
  ServiceSAO [id=SAO]
  ServiceInput [id=Input, detail=foobar]
```

Enjoy and feel free to ask if you do not understand or need a modification which you have not explained previously.

Comment: Hmmm...It does work. Nice. Although by now I changed my architecture so much it doesn't require this now. Will have this in in mind.

Comment: If you just copy & paste my code it works 100%, because I copied it directly from my IDE. If it does not work you must have modified something in a wrong way or have problems with using the AspectJ compiler or similar. I suggest you copy everything incl. package names and test with pure AspectJ, then work your way from that.

Answer (score 0):

AspecJ provides the `this` or `target` pointcut designators and they can be used as *parameter binding*. They allow the advice to get the target object (in your case `serviceInput`) as a parameter.

Syntax :

```
@After("execution(* com.xyz.ServiceInput.setDetails(..)) && @annotation(PublishEventToService)") && target(serviceInput)
public void publishEvent(ServiceInput serviceInput))
{
    String detail = serviceInput.getDetails();   // should work fine
    //someFuntion(serviceSAO, serviceInput);     // but no use for serviceSAO instance
}
```

Anyway, your services should be singletons, so you can get them through dependency injection.